# Troubleshoot networking and DNS, browsers fail to load sites first time

Tags: networking, dns, troubleshooting

Every time I want to visit a website, I first get

> Unable to resolve the server's DNS address.

Doesn't matter what browser. When I refresh a couple of times, the page opens.

I tried flushing my DNS cache, and reinstalling network adapter driver. Didn't work.
I tried using Google's public DNS server (8.8.8.8), still didn't work.

I tried debugging DNS lookup with this command:

```
nslookup -debug www.google.com 8.8.8.8
```

and it worked sporadically. It would work a couple of times, and then for 2-3 minutes it would return "DNS request timeout". All the while a torrent file is happily downloading in the background, so I guess new connections are a problem.

When I use other computers on my network, everything works OK. I'm using cable connection, not Wi-Fi.

How can I troubleshoot what's going on with my networking?

Comment: [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and a book on TCP/IP ([Comer](http://www.amazon.com/Internetworking-TCP-Vol-1-Principles-Architecture/dp/0130183806), [Stevens](http://www.amazon.com/TCP-Illustrated-Vol-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0201633469), ...)

Comment: It's been long since I've learned about Wireshark in college. @RedGrittyBrick do you mean that Wireshark could help me with my particular problem?

Comment: Yes, I'd use it to see what is being sent where.

Comment: Tnx @RedGrittyBrick, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

> **what is the best way to troubleshoot what's going on with my networking?**

I'd use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)
to see what is being sent where

and a book on TCP/IP ([Comer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130183806), [Stevens](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633469), ...) to understand why.